# If a Linksys router is plugged into a cable modem, vs a switch is plugged into a cable modem, is there any difference?

Tags: router, switch

Say in the old days when we have a cable modem, and it only has 1 Ethernet socket, we can connect one computer to it.

But we can buy a Linksys router and then able to plug that into the cable modem, and then also connect up to 4 computers to the Linksys router.

AFAIK, the Linksys router is like a router and switch combined?

But instead of getting a $129 Linksys router, we also could buy a $39 switch, and it seems to be able to accomplish the same thing -- is it actually exactly the same, or are they different?  What does the "router" part of the Linksys router provide actually if it seems a switch is all it requires?

P.S. now I remember I was able to access one particular computer by 192.128.1.18 (something like that). Is that DHCP... so a switch probably cannot provide that or can it? I kind of remember when using a simple switch I was able to do that too.

Comment: a switch will pass all ethernet traffic to the other LAN unless it knows that MAC address is not there (unlike a hub which cannot know the MACs).  a router is the gateway to the other LAN which needs all IP address to be in a different subnet.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do will be very limited. One port on the Switch will be the one external IP on the cable modem and you will only be able to hook up one computer to it.

So in what I perceive above (residential setup) you need a router in order to provide a network for computer, phones and whatever. A router takes the external IP input and provides NAT translation to make the network.

Also you can ask your ISP. If they provide a modem with a number of Ethernet ports, then the router may be built in along with Wireless, and you do not even need a switch unless you need more devices.

In a small business environment where the ISP provides 6 IP addresses (normally), you can put a switch there and attach two or more routers to it for various purposes.